# Unable to boot into Grub

Tags: 20.04, grub2, lenovo, thinkpad

So, I've recently installed Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS on my Dad's Lenovo Thinkpad T580 (the same one as mine), and installed Ubuntu on the entire drive. I've tried booting into grub from the boot process, but I can't get into the menu.

Ubuntu boots fine, but I can't get there in case something happens.
Allow me to go into further detail on why.

So after installing Ubuntu, it boots fine with no problems. Whenever I restart or boot the laptop from a shutdown, there is a few second delay. In this delay, it says "To interrupt normal startup, press Enter." and this delay can let me do:

- Diagnostics screen
- Device Boot Menu
- BIOS/UEFI Menu

And other things. Pressing Shift during this sequence does not work, and pressing it again after this delay also does not work, it just boots the operating system.

I've tried looking at other questions and solutions, but none related to this specific problem.

Comment: If the system is booting with UEFI, then you'll want to use the [Esc] button. [This Wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) may help you 

Comment: That takes me to the diagnostics screen, and after that I press any key to resume boot

Comment: If the key is the same as your motherboard firmware then you need to wait long enough for the firmware to pass to the bootloader.

Comment: I was able to get into grub. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, found out holding Esc after the delay boots into Grub.